# function count in sql

Tags: sql, mysql, count

I have the next tables:

```
Users(ID, name, cName) (ID is a primary key)
ID - id of the user
name - name of the user
cName - name of the country where the user lives

Follows(ID1, ID2) (ID1 AND ID2 ARE PRIMARY KEYS)
id1 - id of the user that follows id2
id2 - id of the user being followed by id1

Interactions(authorID, cNum, uID, iType) (ALL OF THE VARIABLES ARE PRIMARY KEYS)
authorID - id of the user that writes content
cNum - serial number of the content
uID - id of the user that interacted with the content 
iType - type of the interaction, it can be from the type "like", "follow", "comment", "share"
```

I want to know all the users that have at least one follower from each country in the database.
I wrote the next code but it’s returning 0 data.

```
SELECT u.ID, u.name
FROM Users u
JOIN Follows f ON u.ID = f.ID2
JOIN Users uf ON f.ID1 = uf.ID
GROUP BY u.ID, u.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT uf.cName) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cName) FROM Users)
```

Zero is not the answer.

Comment: The code is: SELECT u.ID, u.name
FROM Users u
JOIN Follows f ON u.ID = f.ID2
JOIN Users uf ON f.ID1 = uf.ID
GROUP BY u.ID, u.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT uf.cName) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cName) FROM Users)

Comment: I think your `ON` conditions are backwards. The first should be `f.ID1`, the second should be `f.ID2`.

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected result to the question.

Comment: It would help if you used better column names in `Follows`, e.g. `follower_ID` and `follows_ID`.

Comment: Do you have a list of countries in a table? If so you should probably do `= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Country)`

Comment: Please read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952), then edit your question to add a [mre]

Comment: Your query looks logically fine. As others have said, a minimal reproducible example would help. Food for thought though - a database will consider absolutely any variation as a distinct value, more so than a human would. So, United Arab Emirates and UAE would be different, united states vs. United States, etc... Anything that is not the exact same string.

Comment: @Error_2646 I don't know, I work like that also, and I'm a human (I think...)

Comment: @Charlieface Have you taken a Voight-Kampff test?